# Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+....\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+....\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$

I was thinking of Using Cesaro's lemma.

I define: $S_{n}= 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+....\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

and $T_{n}=\sqrt{n}$

According to the lemma, if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_{n+1}-S_{n}}{T_{n+1}-T_{n}}$ exists then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_{n}}{T_{n}}$ exists and has the same limiting value. So, I am getting the limit to be $0$ .Am I correct?

Comment: I think your idea is right. All the conditions of the lemma are satisfied so the lemma is applies here.

Comment: How is the limit 0?

Comment: After you use Cesaro, rationalize the denominator. The limit comes out to be 2.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint (for an alternative approach):** think "Riemann sums" (this does not exactly applies as it is right away, IIRC, as $f$ below is not Riemann integrable. But the idea is the same, i.e. to compare your sum to an integral, see at the end.)
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{n}{k}}
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
$$
where $f\colon x\in (0,1] \mapsto 1/\sqrt{x}$.

*(Basically, the underlying idea amounts to comparing the behaviour of the partial sums of the divergent series $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ to the integral $\int_1^n \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$, via a comparison series/integral.)*

Comment: To the upvoters: my recollection is that the usual theorem that the Riemann sum converges does not apply here out-of-the-box, since $f$ has some boundedness issues... (but the comparison series/integral does work, though). Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 3):

Let $S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+....\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^{n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\geq S_n\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^{n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+1}}.
$$
Therefore
$$
2\geq S_n\geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}(\sqrt{n+1}-1)
$$
and $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=2$.

Comment: I am sorry, I started writing before I read Clement C.

Comment: Completely fine by me -- you do give details that I don't. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}1\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t^{3/2}}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the floor function. Since $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor =t+O\left(1\right)
 $ we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{t^{1/2}}dt+O\left(\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}dt\right)
 $$ $$=2\sqrt{n}+O\left(1\right)
 $$ so $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=2+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\rightarrow2
 $$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is correct but I think the limit is 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple Riemann sum for the function $\dfrac1{\sqrt x}$ on the interval $(0,1]$ It converges to 
$$\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm d\mkern 1mu x}{\sqrt x}=2\sqrt x\,\Bigr\rvert_0^1=2.$$

Comment: See my answer and the comment below (?)

Comment: @Clement C.: Sorry, I had not seen your answer, and I'll delete mine. As to your question,the sum is almost a Riemann for $\int_{\frac1{2n}}^1$, and it should work, I think.

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering if there was an extended formulation of the theorem that allows application out-of-the-box (also, no worries at all for the duplicate!). if not, a comparison series/integral is straightforward, but requires a bit more elaboration.

Comment: I don't know of any, but I'm no specialist. It suppose it would have to use non-regular subdivisions.

Answer (score 0):

Using $$2\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\leq 2\left(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}\right)$$

So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2\frac{\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{1}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2\frac{\left(\sqrt{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = 2$$